# Docker Power up failed (vrc=VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005)

Tags: docker

I have problem with Docker.

I turned on and turn off Hyper-v, that's not help.

Hyper-v technology - ON ( in BIOS)

[I have this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nWyV.png)

Comment: Please don't send screenshot of your logs, post them directly in your question using code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's help me:
'''
Hey Folks,I too faced above issue,finally I solved my issue following below steps:

1.opened C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox

edited start file as "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check $PROXY_ENV "${VM}"

when docker toolbox was installed it will be as "${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox $PROXY_ENV "${VM}"

if u see hyper vision launcher type status OFF then ts fine if it is AUTO then run bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off to change status to OFF
removed all temp files win+R type temp

4.rebooted my machine

5.open dockerquickstart it worked'''